# How to manually distribute an electron project by using the electron prebuilt binaries?

Tags: node.js, build, electron, software-distribution

I am quite new to electron and the last days I had some trouble manually distributing my app using electrons prebuild binaries and I can’t find any helpful information on the internet. I have also looked multiple times through the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-distribution), but it did not help me!

The problem is that I’m not so familiar with application distribution itself and I'm not sure if there is just something that I’m just not grasping.


This is my structure:

```
src
|--- node_modules [folder]
|
|--- index.html
|--- main.js
|--- package-lock.json
|--- package.json
|--- preload.js
|--- style.css
```

After looking into the source of discord which is also made using electron. I concluded that the manual distribution method has something to do with the dist folder which is located in node_modules/electron folder

```
electron
|--- dist
|    |--- locales [folder]
|    |--- resources [folder]
|    |--- swiftshader [folder]
|    |
|    |--- crome_100_percent.pac
|    |--- crome_200_percent.pac
|    |--- d3dcompiler_47.dll
|    |--- elecron.exe
|    |--- ffmpeg.dll
|    |--- icudtl.dat
|    |--- libEGL.dll
|    |--- libGLE.dll
|    |--- LICENSE
|    |--- LICENSES.chromium.html
|    |--- resources.pac
|    |--- snapshot_blob.bin
|    |--- v8_context_snapshot.bin
|    |--- version
|    |--- vk_swiftshader_icd.json
|    |--- vk_swiftshader.dll
|    |--- vulcan-1.dll
|--- checksums.json
|--- cli.js
|--- electron.d.ts
|--- index.js
|--- install.js
|--- LICENSE
|--- package.json
|--- path.txt
|--- README.md
```

I also tried to copy the whole dist folder. Then I replaced the default app in dist/resources with my index.html, style.css, package.json, preload.js and main.js files and that did work! But I'm sure there should be another way, because this is some kind of unpractical when it comes to larger projects, in my opinion.

But I'm not entirely sure and maybe there is some project structure that makes things easier when it comes to distributing, that I'm just unaware of.

### Side question

I’m also wondering how to include some specific node modules in the build, I hope where is also some better way than copy paste?

### Summery

I hope someone can explain how to manually distribute an electron project by using the electron prebuilt binaries and how to use/add some specific node modules in the distribution?


**--- I'm on a windows machine**.
--- Sorry if I did something wrong whit the structuring of the question, it’s my first time asking a question here (:
--- Please let me know if I could have done something better (:

Comment: I basically just want to know how to distribute my electron project by using the electron prebuilt binaries instead of using some tool like electron-forge.